# is it possible to programatically change an executable name (ucmd) of a unix process?

Tags: linux, unix, net-snmp

Is it possible to programatically change an executable name (ucmd) of a unix process as reported by ps?

unix/POSIX way would be nice but Linux specific solution would suffice.

I want to change what is reported here

```
> ps -o ucmd    
CMD
zsh
ps
```

not this, this I know ;)

```
> ps -o command
COMMAND
zsh
ps -o command
```

thanks

P.S. Not trying to create a rootkit, its just that net-snmp looks at this name when checking processes and my program has a different name when called from init and directly from /etc/init.d (etc/rcX.d/SNNname instead of just name).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but isn't that just the filename of the executable?

Comment: Here is a piece of code that does this trick: http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the `PR_SET_NAME` function of `prctl()`:

```
prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long)"xyzzy", 0, 0, 0);
```

However, `/etc/rcX.d/SNNname` should be a (symlink to a) script that starts your process, not a link to the process executable itself.  This would also solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, there is even a perl module that does exactly what I want http://search.cpan.org/~tlbdk/Sys-Prctl-1.01/lib/Sys/Prctl.pm

Comment: and yes I'm aware that I should actually create a wrapper script, but am trying to keep things simple since my process is already a script itself