# Why does top and ps command shows different names for the same Process Id?

Tags: unix, process

```
$ top | grep myProc  
 1017 deepaky   26   1 2120m 1.8g 2728 R 100.5  3.9  85:52.66 myProcB  
 1063 deepaky   26   1 1488m 1.4g 2804 R 101.0  3.0  87:50.42 myProcC    
 1017 deepaky   26   1 2120m 1.8g 2728 R 99.9  3.9  85:55.67 myProcB  
 1063 deepaky   26   1 1488m 1.4g 2804 R 101.0  3.0  87:50.42 myProcC  

$ ps -f -p 1017  
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD  
deepaky   1017 16624 96 12:43 pts/75   01:26:04 /grid/test1/product201412/Linux64/bin/mytest_proc -test

$ ps -f -p 1063  
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD  
deepaky   1063 16624 92 12:43 pts/75   01:28:35 /grid/test1/product201412/Linux64/bin/mytest_proc -test
```

Why top shows "myProcB" while ps show "mytest_proc" for PID 1017 ?
Why top shows "myProcC" while ps show "mytest_proc" for PID 1063 ?
How the process set these names "myProcB" and "myProcC" ?

Comment: Because there is a different between the "Command Name" and the  "Command Line". I suggest you take a look into tops man page?

Comment: Try running `top -c`

Comment: How the set a command Name for a process ?

Comment: See this for changing the command Name 
[programatically change an executable name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841795/is-it-possible-to-programatically-change-an-executable-name-ucmd-of-a-unix-pro